# jquery Load function with multiple values

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, umbraco

I have a function I are calling

```
public ActionResult MemberMaintenance(int MemId)

using jquery I can call this function
$.ajax {
    var MemberId = $('#MemberSelect').val();
$('#MemberDetails').load('@Url.Action("MemberMaintenance", "IBDMembershipFormSurface")' + '?MemId=' + MemberId);
}
```

This works fine

But now I need to pass additional integers so the function now looks like

```
public ActionResult MemberMaintenance(int MemId, int NodeID, int GlobalSettingsID)
```

my jquery now looks like

```
$.ajax {
    var MemberId = $('#MemberSelect').val();
    var MId = $('#Model.Id').val();
    var GId = $('#globalSettingsId').val();
     $('#MemberDetails').load('@Url.Action("MemberMaintenance", "IBDMembershipFormSurface")' + '?MemId=' + MemberId + '?NodeID=' + MId + '?GlobalSettingsID=' GId);
}
```

This no action takes place

globalSettingsID is decleated as an int at the start of the html code

Model.Id is the umbraco partial view modal id for the form

I are thinking these are my issue how these are loaded

Comment: Its `'&NodeID=' + MId + '&GlobalSettingsID=' + GId`, not `?NodeID` etc - or use `.load('@Url.Action("MemberMaintenance", "IBDMembershipFormSurface")', { MemID: MemberId, NodeID: MId, GlobalSettingsID: GId } `

Comment: so Im learning jquery here. can you please explane the differance and why used ? and &

Comment: It has nothing to do with jquery. The `?` is for the start of a url query string. Every subsequent name/value pair must use `&` - refer [Query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: ok so I have tried both options $('#MemberDetails').load('@Url.Action("MemberMaintenance", "IBDMembershipFormSurface")' + '?MemId' + MemberId + '&NodeID' + MId + '&GlobalSettingsID' + GID); and $('#MemberDetails').load('@Url.Action("MemberMaintenance", "IBDMembershipFormSurface")', { MemId: MemberId, NodeID: MId, GlobalSettingsID: GId } ); and removing the var MId and GId and using $('#MemberDetails').load('@Url.Action("MemberMaintenance", "IBDMembershipFormSurface")', { MemId: MemberId, NodeID: Model.Id, GlobalSettingsID: globalSettingsId } ); none of which worked.

Comment: You should read my comments carefully - you are missing the `=` in the first and your 2nd example not what I told you (`Model.Id` is not `MId` and `globalSettingsId ` is not `Gid`)

Comment: fault of retyping in to browser. the error is not in the .load if I replace     var MId = $('#Model.Id').val();
    var GId = $('#globalSettingsId').val(); with varMId = 100; var GId = 100; then this works                 $('#MemberDetails').load('@Url.Action("MemberMaintenance", "IBDMembershipFormSurface")' + '?MemId=' + MemberId + '&NodeID=' + MId + '&GlobalSettingsID=' + GId); how do I load MId and GId with Model.Id and globalSettingsId as above. this is why the is an example with MId and GId replaced

Comment: What in the world is wrong with just using your existing code and replacing the 2 x `?` with `&` so its a valid query string?

Comment: Thanks Stephen for you help. As I said above your changes fixed that line there is a secondary issue.MID needs to be set var MId = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Id)); and I need to figure out how to load GId. I will start a new topic as that is going away from the original topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was remove GId at this point.

Change var MId to `var MId = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.Id));`

and .load routine to

```
$('#MemberDetails').load('@Url.Action("MemberMaintenance", "IBDMembershipFormSurface")' + '?MemId=' + MemberId + '&NodeID=' + MId);
```